# Conversion CMYK => RGB has incorrect colors although using color profiles

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, cmyk, color-profile

I have an CMYK tif image and want to convert it to an RGB jpeg/png using ImageMagick. The tif image has an profile integrated but is not converted correctly (colors completely incorrect) by ImageMagick even if i specify the sRGB profile manually.

Currently i am using this test file:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-8686107/testimage.tif.html

I tried the following commands (without any success):

```
convert testimage.tif test.jpg
convert testimage.tif -colorspace RGB test.jpg
convert testimage.tif -colorspace sRGB test.jpg
convert testimage.tif -profile sRGB.icm test.jpg
convert testimage.tif -profile USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile sRGB.icm test.jpg
```

Does anybody has an idea why none of this converts the image correctly? Currently i am using

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```